# Unable to form the foooter

Tags: html, css

I'm new in coding. I was watching a tutorial and even though I copied the code exactly (I think) the background color is not applied on the footer and the paddings are not working.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#phonebar {
    background-color:#343434;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align:right;
}

header {
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
    padding: 18px 0;
}

h1 {
font-weight: normal;
color:#696969;
font-size:34px;
margin:0;   
float:left;
}

ul {
    margin:0
}

nav { 
     float:right;
}

li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    margin-top:12px;
}

#important {
    padding: 40px 0;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    width: 510px;
}

#left h1 {
    float:none;
}

img {
    float: right;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

p {
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 30px;
   color: #7f7f7f;  
}

#moreinfo {
    background-color: #343434;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.col {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #b0b0b0;
}

foooter {
    background-color: #252525;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

footer span {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Some Company</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="phonebar">
         <div class="wrapper">
            Find out more by calling 900-555-2300
         </div>
      </div>
      <header>
         <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Some Company, Inc.</h1>
            <nav>
               <ul>
                  <li>Home</li>
                  <li>About</li>
                  <li>Products</li>
                  <li>Contact</li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
      </header>
      <div id="important">
         <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="left">
               <h1>This is Cool</h1>
               <p>A super PAC supporting Mr. Kasich quickly swiped back at Mr. Bush, mocking him for a “campaign that sunk like a rock.” At the same time, a super PAC backing Mr. Rubio continues to blast Mr. Christie, reminding Republicans of the scandal involving the governor’s aides over the shutdown of the George Washington Bridge, and of his embrace of President Obama in 2012 after Hurricane Sandy hit New Jersey.</p>
            </div>
            <img src="something" alt="dog" />
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="moreinfo">
         <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="col">
               <h2>Another Header</h2>
               <p>A super PAC supporting Mr. Kasich quickly swiped back at Mr. Bush, mocking him for a “campaign that sunk like a rock.” At the same time, a super PAC backing Mr. Rubio continues to blast Mr. Christie, reminding Republicans of the scandal involving the governor’s aides over the shutdown of the George Washington Bridge, and of his embrace of President Obama in 2012 after Hurricane Sandy hit New Jersey.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
               <h2>Another Header</h2>
               <p>A super PAC supporting Mr. Kasich quickly swiped back at Mr. Bush, mocking him for a “campaign that sunk like a rock.” At the same time, a super PAC backing Mr. Rubio continues to blast Mr. Christie, reminding Republicans of the scandal involving the governor’s aides over the shutdown of the George Washington Bridge, and of his embrace of President Obama in 2012 after Hurricane Sandy hit New Jersey.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
               <h2>Another Header</h2>
               <p>A super PAC supporting Mr. Kasich quickly swiped back at Mr. Bush, mocking him for a “campaign that sunk like a rock.” At the same time, a super PAC backing Mr. Rubio continues to blast Mr. Christie, reminding Republicans of the scandal involving the governor’s aides over the shutdown of the George Washington Bridge, and of his embrace of President Obama in 2012 after Hurricane Sandy hit New Jersey.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <footer>
         <div class="wrapper">
            &copy; Copyright Some Company
            <span>contact@example.com</span>
         </div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Foooter writed with tooooo many ooos in your CSS code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see the problem.

```
foooter {
   background-color: #252525;
   color: #b0b0b0;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 15px 0;
}
```

You wrote footer with three **o**'s instead of only two.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's embarrassing when it's a small mistake like that. I tried every possible way to clear the float or different version of that and the error was caused by a typo... Thank you again.

Comment: Yeah, no prob bro! It's perfectly natural to make mistakes like that :D Get used to it.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as correct? It helps other people finding correct answers. Thanks